# Understanding Closest Pair Algorithm (CLRS)

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

I'm reading CLRS Section `33.4 Finding the closest pair of points`. At exercise 
`33.4-2` they say

> **33.4-2**
>
> Show that it actually suffices to check only the points in the 5 array positions following each point in the array Y'

But I'm getting 4 array positions following each point in the array Y' will be suffice to check. See the fig below

[image]

Which possibility I'm missing. Can anybody point it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that a point exists in every corner in the figure (including the inside corners). If points cannot overlap, then you have 6 points that can reside in the x2 box, and since you must be looking at one of them, you need only compare it to the next 5 in Y'.